# Importing a user defined class in java

Tags: java, java-7

The below is a test code where I am getting an error `Pizza order = new Pizza();` I believe that I didn't import Pizza.class to Pizzaorder.class file. Can anybody help me in fixing this error.

Code follows.

Pizza.java

```
package pizza;
public class Pizza {
        private double cost; //the cost of the pizza
    private String crust; //the type of crust
    private int size; //the diameter in inches
    private int numToppings; //the number of toppings
    private String toppingList; //a list of the toppings
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
    public Pizza()
    {
        cost = 12.99;
        crust = "Hand-tossed";
        size = 12;
        numToppings = 0;
        toppingList = null;
    }
    public void setCost (double amount)
        {
            cost += amount;
        }
    public void setCrust (String type)
    {
        crust = type;
    }
    public void setSize (int diameter)
    {
        size = diameter;
    }
    public void setNumToppings(int number)
    {
        numToppings = number;
    }
    public void setToppingList (String newTopping)
    {
        toppingList = newTopping;
    }
    public double getCost()
    {
        return cost;
    }
    public String getCrust()
    {
        return crust;
    }
    public int getSize()
    {
        return size;
    }
    public int getNumToppings()
    {
        return numToppings;
    }
    public String getToppingList()
    {
        return toppingList;
    }
}
```

PizzaOrder.java

```
package pizza;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PizzaOrder {
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
                Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
                Pizza order = new Pizza ();
                String firstName;
        boolean discount = false;
                int inches; 
        char crustType; 
        double cost; 
        final double TAX_RATE = .08;
        double tax;
        char choice; 
        String input;
        String toppings = "Cheese ";
        int numberOfToppings = 0;
        System.out.println("Welcome to Abdul and " +
        "Diane’s Pizza");
        System.out.print("Enter your first name: ");
        firstName = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Pizza Size (inches)     Cost");
        System.out.println("        10          £10.99");
        System.out.println("        12          £12.99");
        System.out.println("        14          £14.99");
        System.out.println("        16          £16.99");
        System.out.println("What size pizza would you like?");
        System.out.print("10, 12, 14, or 16 " + "(enter the number only): ");
        inches = keyboard.nextInt();
        keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What type of crust do you want? ");
        System.out.print(
        "(H)Hand-tossed, (T) Thin-crust, or " +
        "(D) Deep-dish (enter H, T, or D): ");
        input = keyboard.nextLine();
        crustType = input.charAt(0);
                System.out.println("All pizzas come with cheese.");
        System.out.println(
        "Additional toppings are £1.25 each,"
        + " choose from");
        System.out.println(
        "Pepperoni, Sausage, Onion, Mushroom");
        System.out.print("Do you want Pepperoni? (Y/N): ");
        input = keyboard.nextLine();
        choice = input.charAt(0);
        if (choice == 'Y' || choice == 'y')
        {
            numberOfToppings += 1;
            toppings = toppings + "Pepperoni ";
        }
        System.out.print("Do you want Sausage? (Y/N): ");
        input = keyboard.nextLine();

        choice = input.charAt(0);
        if (choice == 'Y' || choice == 'y')
        {
            numberOfToppings += 1;
            toppings = toppings + "Sausage ";
        }
        System.out.print("Do you want Onion? (Y/N): ");
        input = keyboard.nextLine();

        choice = input.charAt(0);
        if (choice == 'Y' || choice == 'y')
        {
            numberOfToppings += 1;
            toppings = toppings + "Onion ";
        }
        System.out.print("Do you want Mushroom? (Y/N): ");
        input = keyboard.nextLine();
        choice = input.charAt(0);
        if (choice == 'Y' || choice == 'y')
        {
            numberOfToppings += 1;
            toppings = toppings + "Mushroom ";
        }
        order.setNumToppings (numberOfToppings);
        order.setToppingList(toppings);
        order.setCost(1.25*numberOfToppings);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Your order is as follows: ");
        System.out.println(order.getSize() + " inch pizza");
        System.out.println(order.getCrust() + " crust");
        System.out.println(order.getToppingList());
        cost = order.getCost();
                System.out.println("The cost of your order is: £" +
        cost);
        tax = cost * TAX_RATE;
        System.out.println("The tax is: £" + tax);
        System.out.println("The total due is: £" +
        (tax+cost));
        System.out.println("Your order will be ready" +
        " for pickup in 30 minutes.");
    }
}
```

**Error:**

```
C:\Users\Meutex\Documents\Netbeans projects>javac PizzaOrder.java
PizzaOrder.java:23: error: cannot find symbo
```

**Additional error.**

```
C:\Users\Meutex\Documents\Netbeans projects\Pizza>java Pizza.PizzaOrder
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Pizza/PizzaOrder (wro
ng name: pizza/PizzaOrder)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:14
2)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:472)
```

Comment: Why do you think you have such a problem? What error/problem do you have exactly?

Comment: I edited my question please go thorough it.

Comment: Not related to your question, but in Java, you don't need to declare all variables at the first lines of a function. It is usually a better practice to declare a variable as closest as possible to where it is first used. [for examples the variables `tax` or `cost` in `main()` in your code]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041543/package-not-found-javac, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926931/compiling-java-using-command-line-javac are examples of the same problem

Comment: Get a good IDE and let the IDE compile your code.

Comment: @Mat - your links didn't help me.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut - I am using netbeans and I couldn't understand how to run a console application in netbeans. can you pleaes tell me how>

Comment: @KarsM: It is just a general tip, not related to your question and will not solve your problem, but is a better coding practice. Instead of declaring all variables at the beginning of the method, like you do in `main()`, you should usually declare them when you first use them, it makes the code more readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're not compiling both files.

Change `javac PizzaOrder.java` to be `javac PizzaOrder.java Pizza.java`

**Edit:**

To run your program, put `PizzaOrder.class` and `Pizza.class` in a directory called `pizza`. From the parent directory of `pizza` run `java pizza.PizzaOrder`.

Comment: By running so I am getting errors. I add this to my question. Please look at it.

Comment: From the parent directory (IE `C:\Users\Meutex\Documents\Netbeans projects`) run `java pizza.PizzaOrder`. Java is case sensitive, your package name is `pizza` with a lower-case p, so on the command line ensure you use a lower-case p in the package name.

Comment: Yeah! I got it Andrew.. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

When you have declared the classes in the package pizza, all the compiles class files should go inside a folder pizza. To achieve this, do the following.

1. Keep the files in a directory, say `Project`.
2. On the command line, go to `Project` folder.
3. Create a folder `build` inside the `Project` folder.
4. Copy all your .java files to Project folder.
5. On the command line, compile the code with -d option. i.e. execute `javac -d build *.java`
   You will see another folder `pizza` created inside the `build` folder.
6. To run the application, do `cd build`.
7. Type `java pizza.PizzaOrder`

Answer (score 0):

Pizza.java and PizzaOrder.java are in package pizza, therefore should be in a folder named pizza.
If you're not compiling both files together, the classpath must be set so that the compiler can find pizza/Pizza.class when compiling PizzaOrder.java.

UPDATE:

Let's say the current directory is C:\Users\Meutex\Documents\Netbeans projects (btw, why are You not using netbeans to compile your project), and your pizza directory is inside it, then the command would be:

```
javac -cp . pizza/PizzaOrder.java
```

Comment: how to compile with classpath?

Answer (score 0):

Below  is the output from your program: It seems to work.
Do you have both your classes in the same folder called "pizza"?

```
Welcome to Abdul and Diane’s Pizza
Enter your first name: K
Pizza Size (inches)     Cost
        10          £10.99
        12          £12.99
        14          £14.99
        16          £16.99
What size pizza would you like?
10, 12, 14, or 16 (enter the number only): 10
What type of crust do you want? 
(H)Hand-tossed, (T) Thin-crust, or (D) Deep-dish (enter H, T, or D): T
All pizzas come with cheese.
Additional toppings are £1.25 each, choose from
Pepperoni, Sausage, Onion, Mushroom
Do you want Pepperoni? (Y/N): Y
Do you want Sausage? (Y/N): Y
Do you want Onion? (Y/N): Y
Do you want Mushroom? (Y/N): Y

Your order is as follows: 
12 inch pizza
Hand-tossed crust
Cheese Pepperoni Sausage Onion Mushroom 
The cost of your order is: £17.990000000000002
The tax is: £1.4392000000000003
The total due is: £19.4292
Your order will be ready for pickup in 30 minutes.
```

There are a lot of considerations regarding the "style" of your program, 
like curly brace-placement, defining variables at the top of the methods like in C,
and not dividing the main class into smaller methods, but for a beginner, it is ok.

Comment: Well, I add both the file to folder Pizza and I compiled both and I got 2 more files Pizza.class and PizzaOrder.class but how to run this code?

Comment: I used Eclipse. But it's possible to start the class using the executable `java`; In the folder which contains the folder `pizza`, run `java pizza.PizzaOrder`

Answer (score -1):

If a class has a package it cannot be simply compiled by the program name with extension `javac Pizza.java`. A directory has to be created for storing the particular classes in its package. It should be compiled using `javac -d . Pizza.java` command where `.` will create the folder of package in the current directory. To create the folder in another location mention the location name like `javac -d  e:\user Pizza.java`